# Устройство backend-ов с постоянным соединением

Tags: сокеты, backend, daemon

Правильно ли я понимаю, что современные мессенджеры (клиенты iOS/Android) держат постоянное соединение с сервером, иначе каким образом отправленное сообщение с клиента А мгновенно приходит клиенту Б?

Если так, то получается сервера работают в формете Демона (кажется так называется), то есть постоянно крутится цикл в котором принимается новый запрос от установленного клиента за счет сокетов, например, и в нем выполняется логика?

Конечно это абстрактное описание, больше интересует сама концепция применимо к PHP. Обычно сервер принемает http запрос, приложение заного реализует логику запроса и отдает ответ. Так работает сайт. А как реализовать на том же сервере дополнительно реализцию постоянного соединения с клиентом используя сокеты?

Comment: HTTP Long Polling

Comment: @Suvitruf А как же websocket?

Comment: Я лишь один из возможных вариантов назвал )